# Share a link as a page with php sdk Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
<?php
    session_start();
      require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');
      $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '{app_id}',
        'app_secret' => '{app_secret}',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        ]);

      $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
      $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_pages']; 
      $accessToken = '{access_token}';
      $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = '{access_token}';
      var_dump($fb);
      echo "<br>"."1"."<br>";
      /*try {
        if ($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] !== NULL) {
          $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
          echo "1.1"."<br>";
        } else {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            echo "1.2"."<br>";
            var_dump($accessToken);
            echo "<br>";
        }
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
      }*/
      echo "2"."<br>";
      if (isset($accessToken)) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
          $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
          var_dump($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
          echo "<br>"."3"."<br>";
        } else {
          // getting short-lived access token
          $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
            // OAuth 2.0 client handler
          $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
          // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
          $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
          $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
          // setting default access token to be used in script
          $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
          echo "4"."<br>";
        }
        // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
        /*if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
          header('Location: ./');
        }*/
        echo "5"."<br>";
        // getting basic info about user
        try {
          echo "5.1"."<br>";
          $profile_request = $fb->get('/me');
          echo "5.2"."<br>";
          $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
          echo "5.3"."<br>";
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          session_destroy();
          // redirecting user back to app login page
          header("Location: ./");
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }
        echo "6"."<br>";
        // post on behalf of page
        $pages = $fb->get('/me/accounts');
        $pages = $pages->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
        echo "7"."<br>";
        foreach ($pages as $key) {
          echo "8"."<br>";
          if ($key['name'] == 'name') {
            echo "9"."<br>";
            $post = $fb->post('/' . $key['id'] . '/feed', array('link' => 'http://hexamob.com/review/ulefone-power-review-from-gearbest/'), $key['access_token']);
            $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();
            print_r($post);
          }
        }

        /*
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($pages);
        echo "</pre>";
        */

          // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
      } else {
        echo "fin"."<br>";
        // replace your website URL same as added in te developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://mypage', $permissions);
        echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>'."<br>";
        var_dump($loginUrl);
      }
```

Hi, I'm having problems with the sentence:

$profile_request = $fb->get('/me');

I checked this code in my local server and my Yii2 application and I haven't any problems, but When I check the code in other Yii2 application in this line the code stop.

I have done one thousend tests in other sites and it works perfectly. I don't understand. Wich problems can do this sentence? The error.log don't say anything.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope that you can understand something.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is the php version issue on your server.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); place this on top and check the errors.

Comment: The version is php 5.5.9. The version are the same in both servers.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); no reports any problem.

Comment: var_dump($profile_request); what's the output of this?

Comment: Nothing, because the last sentence that displays is 'echo "5.1";'